# Generating $\LaTeX$ source for binomial expansion

Tags: text, latex

The binomial expansion is of the form

$(x+y)^n = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n {n \choose i} x^i y^{n-i}$.

I'd like to generate the appropriate *Mathematica* output (so I can then convert it to $\LaTeX$ source through `TeXForm[]`) showing each term.  For instance, for $(x+y)^5$ I would like (after conversion and typesetting):

$1 x^0 y^5 + 5 x^1 y^4 + 10 x^2 y^3 + 10 x^3 y^2 + 5 x^4 y^1 + 1 x^5 y^0$.

The first step in my first attempt is:

``` myelements = Table[{ToString[Binomial[5, i]],
  StringForm["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(``\)]\)", i],
  StringForm["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(``\)]\)", 5 - i]}, 
  {i, 0, 5}] ```

giving

``` {{"1", StringForm["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(``\)]\)", 0], 
  StringForm["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(``\)]\)", 5]}, {"5", 
  StringForm["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(``\)]\)", 1], StringForm[
  "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(``\)]\)", 4]}, {"10", StringForm[
  "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(``\)]\)", 2], StringForm[
  "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(``\)]\)", 3]}, {"10", StringForm[
  "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(``\)]\)", 3], StringForm[
  "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(``\)]\)", 2]}, {"5", StringForm[
  "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(``\)]\)", 4], StringForm[
  "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(``\)]\)", 1]}, {"1", StringForm[
  "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(``\)]\)", 5], StringForm[
  "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(``\)]\)", 0]}} ```

to get the individual terms, but unfortunately these elements are not easily joined (since they are not all `Strings` or `Text`), nor is the separating "+" sign appearing.  Then:

```
Flatten@Riffle[myelements, Table["+", {5}]]
```

There must be a way using Text or Boxes or whatever that yields a form that can be converted to $\LaTeX$, but I'm seeking the most elegant method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order is reversed, but you could try:

```
Sum[With[{b = Binomial[5, i], xexp = i, yexp = 5 - i}, 
  HoldForm[b] HoldForm[x^xexp] HoldForm[ y^yexp]], {i, 0, 5}];
% // TeXForm
```

> $1 x^5 y^0+5 x^4 y^1+10 x^3 y^2+10 x^2 y^3+5 x^1 y^4+1 x^0 y^5$

Comment: With the trivial fix of `xexp = 5-i` and `yexp = i`, this is perfect.  Thanks!